# Why is Redis Streams minimum message ID '0-1'?

Tags: redis

The timestamp minimum is 0, and the sequence part starts at 0. Why is Redis Streams minimum message ID '0-1' and not '0-0'?

Is '0-0' used internally? Is this why you can have 'empty' streams?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug - there is an open pull request to fix it at https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/6574

Comment: I see the pull request has been merged. It confirms 0-0 is not used internally, but my question remains, why is '0-0' not a valid message ID for a Redis stream?

Comment: I don't see a reason why 0-0 shouldn't be a legit ID. Perhaps there are other issues :)

Answer (score 0):

This makes perfect sense. If id `0-0` was allowed, there'd be no way to start fetching stream from the very beginning if using an explicit index (as opposed to `-`). Sometimes it is convenient to use an explicit index and not `-`.

In other words, it would be confusing and undesirable if simply passing `0` would result in skipping first element.